# VBA, empty cell is at last row

Tags: excel, vba

In a VBA Excel macro, 
I copy rows from another sheet, select a different sheet, and try to find the next open cell before pasting them.

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

The page has a first row of column titles, and find then passes over these to the very last row???

[image: https://ibb.co/kjdWi0]

If dummy data

[image]

is put in the second row, or if there is data already present,

[image]

it works.

[image]

WHY is it doing this?

Answer (score 2):

`Range.End(xlDown)` is equivalent to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Test it on your own - if you only have a header in Row 1, then you'll jump to the last row in the `Worksheet`. If you have data below the header, you'll move to that row.

Use `Range.End(xlUp)` to find the next available row by moving *up* from the last row on the `Worksheet` - something like this:

```
With Sheet1
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

standing your data layout, you can use:

```
Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

or, using explicit worksheet references (recommended):

```
With Worksheets("mySheetName")
    .Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```